# Angular 6: Change Content-Type of template-generated page

Tags: excel, angular, templates, content-type, xls

Notice: This question is not about ANGULAR's HttpClient, but the document generated by a component's template.

I want to do an old trick for a simple, yet powerful MS EXCEL export: Generate an HTML document containing one single <table>, and serve it with "Content-Type: application/xls". The user's browser will forward the document to a locally installed MS EXCEL, which detects that this is not a "real" .xls, but HTML, and converts very nicely the HTML into a spreadsheet.

My approach to implement this is straigtforward: Add a route for path, say, "/export-xls", and a new component that gets the data and renders it in its template.

However I absolutely cannot find a way to set the "Content-Type" header in the response!? I envisage that in the "Routes" array I would set "contentType: 'application/xls'", but no way.

What is the easiest and best way to generate such a document from within ANGULAR?

Comment: As for as i know, Angular allows setting content-type only to HTTP Request. Setting content type for the component templates is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by doing following steps

1. create a file containing your table in your local file system and create a URL for that file using URL.createObjectURL method
2. send an http request to that file
3. intercept the request and add contentType: 'application/xls' to response headers
4. after receiving your file revoke the URL using URL.revokeObjectURL method and delete the file from your local file system

I am not sure if you can do this without the creation of physical file because you need an http request because of the response content type

Comment: With "local", do you mean on the server or on the client?

Comment: You can do that on the client side. All you have to do is when you create an object make a URL for that object. You can do that using URL.createObjectURL method. Before deleting the object you can revoke the URL using URL.revokeObjectURL method