# Angular: Return JSON instead of template

Tags: json, angular

Is there a way for an Angular component to act like an API and return JSON data (with application/json header) instead of returning a content template? Something like pure "controller" in MVC without the V(iew) part.

I've seen some recommendations to list it in the "assets" property as a static file, but it doesn't serve my purpose because I want to serve it as a dynamically-generated content not as a static JSON file.

Comment: What about a [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services-and-dependency-injection)?

Comment: Angular services are not handled by routes, therefore, not directly served by the server.

Comment: You can configure proxy rules in angular.json and there you could handle stuff that is dynamic, but not directly part of your angular app. Mostly the case for backend calls. Is that something for you?

Comment: This could help you too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710022/angular-6-change-content-type-of-template-generated-page

Comment: Thanks, @JanosVinceller, sadly, I do not intend to serve XLS files. I guess I will have to create a separate API project as Angular might not be intended to serve data.

Comment: You can also serve a component that is creating a dynamic file via javascript (or in this case TypeScript) that can be downloaded by the user. That way you could have the dynamic part but not serve it exactly as the view part (but better as a part of a view).

Comment: You can create a Blob like this: const blob = new Blob(data, { type: 'microsoft/excel' }); and then create a downloadable URL for it: const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);